# intellij idea UNDERSCOREJS / EJS formatter

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, formatting

I registered *.tpl file type as a "Java Server Page" file, although it's an UnderscoreJS template code (JavaScript! Not Java as the file editor points, due to this configuration).

It's all nice but the **formatting breaks** the code lines of my EJS style template code, as shown in the following image:

[image]

I've managed to **isolate** the problem - it breaks when my code uses Underscore.JS' **`each()`** function, i.e code like the following creates the breaking (otherwise it would format nicely):

```
_.each(models, function(model) {
        // some code..
    }
);
```

What can be done? I'm looking for a "native" solution, i.e not use Eclipse formatting plugin.

Maybe associate the file type with another editor? Then, which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an EJS plugin in IDEA 13.

Comment: The question referred to v12.